# i want to install seagate crystal reports v7.0 in windows 7

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having a Segate crystal Report 7.0. I am using this in one of my Vb6 project.Now for developing applications I need to install Segate crystal report 7.0 on Windows 7.0. But I am not able to install. When Try to install. Ater 16 % of installation it shows error and exits. i want to install seagate crystal reports v7.0 on windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide the exact error message you get? Also, is it a 64x or 86x version of windows?

Comment: Have you considered using a newer development environment and version of CR?